# Copying values from sortedset to array

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, sortedset

I'm currently working on a project where i use a sorted set and I then need to put them in an array to iterate over it using index. I came to a strange problem where the CopyTo method wasn't working properly and I'd like to know if there is a real reason for it. My code was:

```
SortedSet<float> zValuesSet = new SortedSet<float>();

//Insert some values in the set

float[] zValues = new float[zValuesSet.Count];
zValuesSet.CopyTo(zValues);
```

Using this, i came with an error telling me the I was assigning more values in zValues than its capacity, even if I used the Set.Count to get the capacity. To solve my problem, I used:

```
List<float> zValuesList = new List<float>(zValuesSet);
float[] zValues = zValuesList.ToArray();
```

However, this may lead to a cost that (I guess ?) could be avoided using the first method. So I'm wondering about why this happends ?

EDIT : That was my bad, I'm using multiple occurencies of this kind of set and I misspelled it... So the copy to is working well.

Comment: How many values do you have inside a `zValuesSet`? Did you insert some duplicate values? Because I can't reproduce with few simple values

Comment: and what is your question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly convert to an array this way:

```
 SortedSet<float> zValuesSet = new SortedSet<float> { 1, 2, 3 };

 float[] zValues = zValuesSet.ToArray();
```

Here working: https://ideone.com/xphVAJ

Comment: That's what i wanted to use at first but I get an error when writing it, saying this is not defined for SortedSet

Comment: which version of framework are you using? I tested here and it´s working with core 2.0

Comment: I've tested with .net standard and core and worked fine, I think you're missing a `using System.Linq`. Moreover, it also worked with `CopyTo`

Comment: Was not using System.Linq, that's much better now thanks